# switch to ruby version installed through RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

my macbook is OSX El Capitan. It has Apple pre-installed universal **Ruby version 2.0.0**.

Now, I want to use latest **Ruby 2.3.0**. I managed to use **rvm** to install Ruby 2.3.0. I see the following message after **rvm** finished installing ruby 2.3.0:

```
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
/Users/John/.rvm/bin/rvm: line 66: shell_session_update: command not found
Creating alias default for ruby-2.3.0...

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/John/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.
```

I followed this message, & run command

```
source /Users/John/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

but when I run `ruby -v`, the version is still Apple pre-installed Ruby 2.0.0. How can I switch to the ruby I installed through **rvm**?

(under path `.rvm/rubies` I can find ruby-2.3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch to using 2.3.0, do

```
rvm use 2.3.0
```

To make it default, do

```
rvm use --default 2.3.0
```

Comment: you can see all the installed rubies by running `rvm list`